# Как в xaml ограничить ориентацию экрана у отдельной страницы?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Как в xaml или в коде ограничить ориентацию экрана у отдельной страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [этой статье](http://igrali.com/2014/07/21/set-supported-orientations-xaml-windows-phone-8-1/), вы должны указать в code-behind (например, в конструкторе после `InitializeComponent()`) что-нибудь вроде

```
this.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
```